# Find ec2 instances with improper or missing tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, tags, command-line-interface, jq

I am trying to simply output a list of all instance IDs that do not follow a particular tagging convention.

1. Tag is missing (Tag Keys: Environment or Finance)
2. Environment Tag value is not one of (prod, stg, test, dev)
3. Finance Tag value is not one of (GroupA , GroupB)

---

For (1) I can use the following:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?!not_null(Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value)] | [].InstanceId'
[
    "i-12345678901234567", 
    "i-76543210987654321"
]
```

---

But I still need (2) and (3).  What if the tag exists but is empty, or has a typo in the value?

"ec2 --query" functionality is limited and I've yet to find a way for it to get me (2) or (3), especially when it comes to inverting results.

I've gone back and forth trying to

- modify the output from the CLI to make it easier to parse in JQ

VS

- trying to wrangle the output in JQ

For (2) and (3).  Here's a pair of outputs from the CLI that I've tried sending to JQ to parse with sample output for 2 instances:

**CLI Sample Output [A]** Tag.Value and Tag.Key need to be paired when searching, and then negating/inverting a set of searches...

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId, Tag: Tags[]}' | jq '.[]'
{
  "Tag": [
    {
      "Value": "GroupA",
      "Key": "Finance"
    },
    {
      "Value": "stg",
      "Key": "Environment"
    },
    {
      "Value": "true",
      "Key": "Backup"
    },
    {
      "Value": "Another Server",
      "Key": "Name"
    }
  ],
  "ID": "i-87654321"
}
{
  "Tag": [
    {
      "Value": "GroupB",
      "Key": "Finance"
    },
    {
      "Value": "Server 1",
      "Key": "Name"
    },
    {
      "Value": "true",
      "Key": "Backup"
    },
    {
      "Value": "stg",
      "Key": "Environment"
    }
  ],
  "ID": "i-12345678"
}
```

**CLI Sample Output [B]** Tag value being inside an array has been enough to trigger syntax errors when attempting things like "jq map" or "jq select"

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId, EnvTag: Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value, FinTag: Tags[?Key==`Finance`].Value}' | jq '.[]'
{
  "EnvTag": [
    "stg"
  ],
  "ID": "i-87654321",
  "FinTag": [
    "GroupA"
  ]
}
{
  "EnvTag": [
    "stg"
  ],
  "ID": "i-12345678",
  "FinTag": [
    "GroupB"
  ]
}
```

I find most of the time, when I try to expand some solution from a simpler use case, I only ever end up with cryptic syntax errors due to some oddity in the structure of my incoming dataset.

---

**Example Issue 1**
Below is an example of how the inverting / negating fails.  This is using CLI output B:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId, EnvTag: Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value, FinTag: Tags[?Key==`Finance`].Value}' | jq '.[]' | jq 'select(.EnvTag[] | contains ("prod", "dev") | not)'
```

I would expect the above to return everything except prod and dev.  But it looks like the logic is inverted on each item as opposed to the set of contains:

- "!A + !B" instead of "!(A or B)"

The resulting dataset returned is a list of everything, including dev and prod.

**Example Issue 1.5**
I can workaround the logic issue by chaining the contain excludes, but then I discover that "contains" won't work for me as it will pickup typos that still happen to contain the string in question:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId, EnvTag: Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value, FinTag: Tags[?Key==`Finance`].Value}' | jq '.[]' | jq 'select(.EnvTag[] | contains ("dev") | not) | select(.EnvTag[] | contains ("stg") | not) | select(.EnvTag[] | contains ("test") | not) | select(.EnvTag[] | contains ("prod") | not) | select (.EnvTag[] | contains ("foo") | not)'
```

- prod != production
- "prod" contains("prod") = true
- "production" contains ("prod") = true <-- bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe I've found a solution.

It can be greatly simplified. First, in this case, there is no need to invoke jq twice. `jq '.[]' | jq ...` is equivalent to `jq '.[] | ...'`

Second, the long pipeline of 'select' filters can be condensed, for example to:

```
select(.EnvTag[]
  | (. != "dev" and . != "stg" and . != "prod" and . != "test" and . != "ops"))
```

or, if your jq has `all/2`, even more concisely to:

```
select( . as $in | all( ("dev", "stg", "prod", "test", "ops"); . != $in.EnvTag[]) )
```

Comment: thanks for the improvements.  As for the extra jq call, that was just an artifact of trying to quickly improve the output of the describe instances call vs the actual jq logic.  I'll give the shortened version a whirl as that does help clean up the call.  And finally, I have no clue what all/2 is, and I'd argue the first condensed solution is a touch easier to read when I inevitably need to revisit this 6 months down the road :)

Comment: jq provides support for a simple form of polymorphism in which [multiple versions of the same function are differentiated by their number of arguments](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#builtins).  Here `/2` in `all/2` indicates the [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of the function e.g. the version of `all` that accepts two arguments [source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L42-L46)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a solution.  It may not be optimal, but I've found a way to pipe-chain excludes of exact strings:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ID:InstanceId, EnvTag: Tags[?Key==`Environment`].Value, FinTag: Tags[?Key==`Finance`].Value}' | jq '.[]' | jq 'select(.EnvTag[] != "dev") | select (.EnvTag[] != "stg") | select (.EnvTag[] != "prod") | select (.EnvTag[] != "test") | select (.EnvTag[] != "ops") | .ID'
```

I verified this by changing an environment tag from "ops" to "oops".

Upon running this query, it returned the single instance with the oops tag.